# How to use VBA in excel to refresh sql data into next empty row?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have a query in excel that brings me back a set of data. I would like to know if it would be possible using VBA that when I refresh the query rather than overwrite the existing data it instead adds this data below the existing data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without more info about how your query dumps the data in your sheet, i can point out to getting last row of your data (try one of these solutions: https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/7/7/5-different-ways-to-find-the-last-row-or-last-column-using-vba).

Having the last row (assigned to a variable), should be just a matter of adding this information in your code, at the part where the data is sent to the sheet.

For better help, please post some/all of your code.